# Segmentation fault when removing from std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, segmentation-fault

I am trying to remove duplications in a vector of struct and this duplication is determined by `qieid` in the struct:

```
struct infotable
{
  int qieid;
  int fid;
  int valid;
};
```

And I write a subfunction to do this:

```
void erase_duplicate(vector<infotable> &info)
{
  vector<infotable>::iterator it0,it1;

  for(it0 = info.begin();it0 != info.end()-1; it0++)
  {
    //it1 = find(qieidarray1.begin(),it0,*it0);

    for(it1 = it0 +1;it1 != info.end(); it1++)
    {
      if((*it1).qieid == (*it0).qieid)
        it1 = info.erase(it1);
    }
  }
}
```

But I have some problems with this piece of code. 
When the number of struct in the vector is small, it works fine. But when I have about more than 3000 structs in the vector, the program will go wrong and I have:

> segmentation fault 11

showed on my screen.
I know it is a memory access problem and I may access to somewhere I should not touch because I have so many elements in the vector. 
But is there anyway I can improve my code in order to get a better performance(run more elements)?

Comment: Have you considered using a set instead of a vector? You will need to write a comparison to tell the set that two structs with the same qieid are equal.

Comment: @katutxakurra That is a good idea! I have never used set before. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use `<algorithm>` functions to do it, [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) in particular.

First, sort by `qieid`, then use `unique`, which moves the "deleted" elements at the end and returns a new iterator, which you can then use to actually erase these elements.

```
std::sort(info.begin(), info.end(), [](const infotable& a, const infotable& b) {
    return a.qieid < b.qieid;
});
auto newIt = std::unique(info.begin(), info.end(), [](const infotable& a, const infotable& b) {
    return a.qieid == b.qieid;
});
info.erase(newIt, info.end());
```

This will run in O(n+log n), whereas your original solution has O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity. Personally, I'd prefer this solution especially because it's more expressive and so it's easier to see what the code is doing.

*Note*: If your compiler already supports C++ 14's generic lambdas, you can simplify the expressions even more by using: `[](const auto& a, const auto& b) { ... }`

Comment: +1, didn't know std::unique, always nice to learn new things

Comment: @Kiroxas yeah there are quite a few goodies hidden in the STL :)

Answer (score 4):

when you use erase, it will invalidate iterators.

```
for(it1 = it0 +1;it1 != info.end(); )
{
   if((*it1).qieid == (*it0).qieid)
      it1 = info.erase(it1);
   else
      it1++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can remove duplicate with the `std::set` trick,
it's quite readable, and easily maintanable, but is less efficient.

```
std::vector<int> r = {14,26,58,56,26,14};

std::set<int> s(r.begin(),r.end());
r = std::vector<int>(s.begin(),s.end());
```

You'll need to give the std::set your own comparison function in order for it to work with your structure.

Comment: "less efficient" - not if he uses the set everywhere instead of the vector :) Anyway, nice and concise solution